# Why can't I install Microsoft SQL Server 2017 or 2016 Express?

Tags: sql-server, windows, installation

My attempt to install Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Express on Windows 10 for development purposes is always failing saying `Opps failed to install` in the installer and giving me the path to the log to see the errors.

I read other issues but they all say to remove the Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable. I did that but the same issue happens. However the SQL Server is appearing in `C:/Program Files` and in the control panel.

**Hint::**

same logs and error appear when downloading sql 2016

**Here is the last part of the log file:**

```
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:23 Slp: Running Action: CloseUI
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:23 Slp: Stop action skipped in UI Mode Quiet
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:23 Slp: Completed Action: CloseUI, returned True
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:23 Slp: Completed Action: ExecuteCloseWorkflow, returned True
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:23 Slp: Completed Action: ExecuteCompleteWorkflow, returned True
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:23 Slp: SetupTelemetry: Writing Telemetry to Datastore
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:26 Slp: 
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:26 Slp: 
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:26 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:26 Slp: 
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:26 Slp: Error result: -2068643839
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:26 Slp: Result facility code: 1203
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:26 Slp: Result error code: 1
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:26 Slp: SetupTelemetry: Closing Telemetry Session
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:26 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:26 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:26 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value MachineId
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\140
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: SetupTelemetry: Not creating telemetry audit log. Value 'UserRequestedLocalAuditDirectory' doesn't exist in 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\140'
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\140
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value CustomerFeedback
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value EnableErrorReporting
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SQL
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value SQLEXPRESS05
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS05\CPE
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value CustomerFeedback
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value EnableErrorReporting
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey OLAP
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey RS
(01) 2018-02-09 20:32:27 Slp: SetupTelemetry: Telemetry has an active session with 57 events.
```

I can't post the entire log file because it's too big